# Pyramid - Include user object in every request and rendering?

Tags: pyramid

In my website I have a user panel which displays info about user (or a custom message if he is not logged in). I'd like to know how can I do that a user object is accessible within every template? (like Django's **CONTEXT_PROCESSORS**).
I know I can **add_request_method()** to my config object but as far as I understand it will only make user's object available in request but I will have to add it to returned context manually each time - not good.
Maybe I should add user's object to session?
What is the proper way to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "it will only make user's object available in request but I will have to add it to returned context manually each time"?

Answer (score 3):

What you need in Pyramid is an authentication policy. This can be as simple as adding these lines to your __init__.py:

```
from pyramid.authentication import AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy

def main(global_config, **settings):
    ...
    authentication_policy = AuthTktAuthenticationPolicy('some_key')
    config = Configurator(settings=settings,
                      authentication_policy=authentication_policy)
    ...
```

Once an authentication policy is in place, you can use the 'forget' and 'remember' functions from pyramid.security to allow users to log in and out. Here's a simplified view function that handles logins:

```
from pyramid.security import remember, forget    

def sign_in(request):
    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')
    if username and User.verify_password(username, password):
        headers = remember(request, username)
    else:
        headers = forget(request)
    return HTTPFound(location=request.route_url('index'),
                 headers=headers)
```

There are a few things you'll have to change there - maybe your User object doesn't have a 'verify_password' method; maybe you want to redirect to a different page on successful login, etc. But it's something to get started with.

Then in my base template I can add:

```
<%
from pyramid.security import authenticated_userid
user_id = authenticated_userid(request)
%>
```

to make the user_id available for use in the template and then:

```
% if user_id:
    <p>Welcome ${user_id}</p>
% else:
    <p>Please login <a href="${request.route_url('login')}">here</a></p>
% endif
```

Note I'm using Mako syntax - if you're using a different templating engine you should check their syntax for imports, conditionals, etc.

I've given a basic outline of the different pieces and how they slot together, but Pyramid has powerful authentication features, and I encourage you to read a little about how it works:

The Pyramid documentation: http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/authentication.html

This excellent demo of Pyramid's authentication policies:
https://github.com/mmerickel/pyramid_auth_demo

Answer (score 1):

I know you already mentioned the `add_request_method()` solution, but that's what I ended up with after following this tutorial on [adding a user object to the request](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_cookbook/en/latest/auth/user_object.html).

I might not be doing anything that out there with my pyramid apps, but basically every view and template I have has a request object as part of it, so within any template I can do `<% request.user %>` and have my user object and everything part of that available.  I even have some helper methods and relationships that just come through and are available automagically as `request.user`.

What example case do you have where the request object isn't available?